# How to use coderpad and swift?

Tags: swift

I am preparing for a technical interview coming up soon and the online IDE is coderpad. I have been trying to run my code for sometime now and it is simply not printing anything. I know the solution has to be something minor. This is my first time working in coderpad is it similar to playgrounds?

Here is my code

```
import Foundation

class Solution{

func findSolution(){

  print("it works")

   }
}
```

When I hit run it just says ***ran 10 lines of Swift 5***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re just declaring the class and its method. But you never run it. You actually have to execute it:

```
import Foundation

class Solution {
    func findSolution() {
        print("it works")
    }
}

let solution = Solution()
solution.findSolution()
```

It’s just like a playground: After you declare your function, you have to call it.